# How to add Facebook FB.ui dialog confirmation message

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have some code that brings up a facebook dialog, after the user shares they are redirected to a URL, which prompts the window to close. How do I pass on some javascript so I can display a confirmation on the current window (i.e. I want the user to be notified that they posted successfully)

I tried a simple alert but only works on the redirected page

```
  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'test',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',
      redirect_uri: 'http://domain.com/dios/index.php/response/'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];

    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

The redirect URL above echos out: self.close();

---

I have tried to do this with an ajax call within the callback.. doesnt work.. any other suggestions..

This is what I changed in the above callback function

```
   function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];

      $.ajax({

             type: "POST",
             url: 'http://domain.com/dios/index.php/response/',
             success: function(data){

                 alert('yes');

             }

             });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy: *Don’t* give a redirect_uri!

That will make the dialog close by itself once it’s done; and then you just evaluate the dialog’s response in your callback function.

Comment: i need the redirect, it does some server side actions.. once the window closes how do I bring up an alert for the current window the user is on

Comment: Can’t you call your server side action by AJAX?

Comment: Depends on whether it’s sensitive data you have to transfer from the client to the server. If manipulation of that data would be bad in your application, then you should go with _sending the data straight from FB to your server_-approach.